# Django - Retrieve Different Post Types Based On TimeStamp

Tags: django

I am working on a little Django project. The user can create two types of Posts: Image & Video .

Here, the different classes I have created (for the sake of brevity, I excluded some fields):

```
class VideoPost:
    videoData = ...

class ImagePost:
    imageData = ...
```

So, when I combined the project with an Android app to display the posts on the screen, then I faced the problem how to retrieve the different posts once. I could not come up with a solution.

Let's say, the user has created video and image post objects with the following order:

```
VideoPost1 -> ImagePost1 -> ImagePost2 -> VideoPost2
```

How can I retrieve them in that order ? So, how to get a that mix of video and image posts based on creation time ?

At the moment, I can only make separate queries like:

```
# the view responsible for listing VideoPost instances
....
return VideoPost.objects.all() 

# the view responsible for listing ImagePost instances
....
return ImagePost.objects.all()
```

I do not want to sort the instances on the frontend (Android app). 
So, is there a way to sort and query the different instances on the backend (Django)

Comment: you can but you need a unified Post model that holds all posts and a generic relationship to their post type. Otherwise you can create an all posts view of some sort that retrieves all video and image posts and then sorts them in code, which would be more inefficient than sorting on the client side as ideally you'd outsource that sort to the client device as your server is shared between all devices and the sort seems to be unique to the user.

Comment: what you mean with generic relationship ? Something like a ForeignKey relationship between the Post class and the special Post classes ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations

Comment: Alternative approach would be to turn the two into lists then merge and sort the two based on timestamp

Comment: can you give me a short models.py example how the generic relationship concept with the unified Posts stuff would work. The examples I searched for generic relationship were not very helpful.